# Replace every second instance of delimiter with a character

Tags: java, string

Input String:

```
"/key1/2/key2/3/key4/5/key6/6/key7/7"
```

Need to Replace every second instance of delimiter `"/"` with `":"`.

This can be manipulated if we break input string separated by `"/"` and construct     output string based on that but need to find the simplest way to do this.

Expected Output String:

```
"/key1:2/key2:3/key4:5/key6:6/key7:7"
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried thus far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "/key1/2/key2/3/key4/5/key6/6/key7/7";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=\\d+)/(?=\\d+)", ":"));
}
```

O/P :

```
/key1:2/key2:3/key4:5/key6:6/key7:7
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
String s = "/key1/2/key2/3/key4/5/key6/6/key7/7";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(/[^/]*)/", "$1:"));
```

**Output:**

```
/key1:2/key2:3/key4:5/key6:6/key7:7
```

This regex would match the forward slashes in pair and it capture the first forward slash and also the following non-`/` characters. By replacing all the matched chars with `$1:` will give you the desired output.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kJ6zS2/6)

Answer (score 0):

Split and rebuild string?

(pseudo-code)

```
boolean first = true;
out = "";
for(s:str.split("/")){
    if(!(first = !first)){
        out += "/"
    }else{
        out += ":"
    }
    out += s;
}
```